# split a string by tab in shell script using awk is not working

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I Have a text file in the following format:

```
Name           Place     Mobile
Jon Sam        India     1234567890
Barack Obama   USA       0987654321
```

Every field is separated by a tab space. I wanted to extract each field through a shell script. I am using the following piece of code:

```
while IFS= read -r var; do 
    echo $var | awk -F"\t" '{print $1,"->"$2,"->"$3}'
done < myfile
```

I am expecting output in the following style:

```
Jon Sam->India->1234567890
```

But it prints like this:

```
Jon Sam India 1234567890-> ->
```

Which means, no split happens. What is wrong with my program?

Comment: First, this seems silly -- why read your input in a `while` loop when you can just have `awk` read `myfile` directly? Second, in bash, ALWAYS quote your variables.  Try with `echo "$var" | awk ...` and see if that makes a difference. And then stop using the while loop entirely.

Comment: .. and why is your expected output `Jon Sam->Kochin->1234567890`, having `Kochin` in the middle, while the input has a different one?

Comment: @ghoti Thanks. I used while loop because on each line I am performing some more operations.

Comment: @Inian That was a mistake. Question modified. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to perform those operations inside awk, in order to avoid running a separate awk instance on each line? And if all you want awk for is to format your output, why not just use `printf` from within bash?  It's built in.

Comment: It's difficult to include inside awk. If running awk instance on each line is costly, do you have any other better solution for the same?

Comment: @BBHeeMAA: Your input file is wrong, you have say it is `\t` separated, but you haven't used tab at all, but just multiple spaces. Remember this matters, when you are using field separators in awk

Comment: @Inian Input file fields are separated by `\t`. for the purpose of readability, Here I separated by multiple spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using awk for only formatting seems wasteful, when you've got perfectly good formatting tools right there in bash.

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r var1 var2 var3; do
    printf "%s->%s->%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
done < myfile
```

Or if you really want to split the line after-the-fact:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    IFS=$'\t' read -r -a arr <<<"$line"
    printf "%s->%s->%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
done < myfile
```

Of course, awk does this kind of stuff effortlessly:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ printf "%s->%s->%s\n",$1,$2,$3 } ' myfile
```

or even

```
awk -F"\t" -v OFS="->" '{ $1=$1 } 1' myfile
```

Comment: Good for the awk versions, they end up being way easier and straight forward than the Bash ones.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your input lines are `\t` separated, an `awk` with `OFS` output-field-separator set to `->` and reconstructing the lines should do the job for you.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="->"}{$1=$1}1' file
Name->Place->Mobile
Jon Sam->India->1234567890
Barack Obama->USA->0987654321
```

Remember the above command works on this input-file which is `\t` separated,

```
$ cat file
Name    Place   Mobile
Jon Sam India   1234567890
Barack Obama    USA     0987654321
```

Observe the `\t` between strings below,

```
hexdump -c file
0000000   N   a   m   e  \t   P   l   a   c   e  \t   M   o   b   i   l
0000010   e  \n   J   o   n       S   a   m  \t   I   n   d   i   a  \t
0000020   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0  \n   B   a   r   a   c
0000030   k       O   b   a   m   a  \t   U   S   A  \t   0   9   8   7
0000040   6   5   4   3   2   1  \n
0000047
```

Now coming to your original input file,

```
hexdump -c original-file
0000000   N   a   m   e                                               P
0000010   l   a   c   e                       M   o   b   i   l   e  \n
0000020   J   o   n       S   a   m                                   I
0000030   n   d   i   a                       1   2   3   4   5   6   7
0000040   8   9   0  \n   B   a   r   a   c   k       O   b   a   m   a
0000050               U   S   A                               0   9   8
0000060   7   6   5   4   3   2   1  \n
0000068
```

Observe the white-spaces, in your file. Operating on this file in `awk` or `bash` with `\t` de-limiter will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It also would be possible to substitute `\t` by '->' with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/\t/->/g' filename.txt
```

Note that this also will apply to the header line, so you may want to exclude it:

```
sed -e '2,$s/\t/->/g' filename.txt
```

However you must ensure that your text file is really separated by one tab between fields.